# Android "Unknown Source" Setting error for API > 17

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-permissions

I have very confusing problem,

If I make a change in anywhere, At the "Global.getInt" part (last line), there is an error

> "Call requires API level 17 (current min is 4):
>   android.provider.Settings.Global#getInt"

after making Project-> Clean, red error disappearing itself. But this error comes very often Why?

```
   public void buton2(View view) throws SettingNotFoundException{
    boolean isNonPlayAppAllowed = false;
 {

     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 5) {

        isNonPlayAppAllowed = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS) == 1;
        }
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) {

            isNonPlayAppAllowed = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS) == 1;
        } else {
            isNonPlayAppAllowed = Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS) == 1;


        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: you need to put your call in a method with the @TargetApi annotation on it.

Comment: Ufff VEry Fast! can you show me an example, How?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592820/writing-backwards-compatible-android-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Call requires API level 17 (current min is 4): android.provider.Settings.Global#getInt

It tells you that your code contains a method that was added in API 17 so the compiler is complaining. Now because you're doing your checks in regards of what API is on the phone, just add this above your method signature, so it looks something like this:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
public void buton2(View view) throws SettingNotFoundException
```

Comment: you are perfect guys!