# Backward compatible java code makes compile error

Tags: java, android, backwards-compatibility

I'm new to android programming .
I know  some functions and classes were not in first android versions so we have to use different codes to work on different versions. For example to set a Button's background color i should use this code:

```
    // Set button background
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        this.setBackground(background);
    } else {
        this.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    }
```

My project's target API version is 11, so `setBackground` produces compile error and `setBackgroundDrawable` produces deprecation warning, how should i change this code or manifest or etc to make this app work on both versions?

In manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: @EDittmer No, all i know about backwards compatibility (in Android!) is what i mentioned in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your backgrounds are resources, definitely follow Oren's answer. But let's assume that you have some other `Drawable` that you wish to use for your background.

To clear up your compile error, you need to be compiling against API Level 16 or higher. In Eclipse, that is Project > Properties > Android from the main menu; in Android Studio, that is the `compileSdkVersion` value in your `build.gradle` file.

You will have to live with the deprecation.

Comment: I'm using eclipse, in project properties window i have Android 4.4 with API Level=19

Comment: @MJafarMash: OK, what is the exact compile error that you are getting? If it is complaining about your `minSdkVersion` being too low, you need to add the `@TargetApi()` annotation to the method that has your code snippet from your question. There's an Eclipse quick-fix (e.g., `Ctrl`-`1`) that should add that for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can (and should) use [setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)) with a reference to your background drawable resource. Available since API 1. As in:

```
this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_backround_resource_id);
```

Comment: I'm editing an open-source code that defined `updateBackground` function with this signature: `private void updateBackground(Drawable background)` so i don't have access to it's ID AFAIK.

Comment: in that case, CommonsWares answer is the way to go. compile your code against API 16 or higher. and live with the deprecation. note that API level 16 also introduces the [@targetAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592820/writing-backwards-compatible-android-code) annotation, which you should use.