# Method api target warning

Tags: android

Im trying to create a library, but some methods will only work for API > 21.

How can I set the minimum api target for this method and show a warning?

like the TextureView for example:

[image: I need to show this warning]

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public CustomTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(attrs);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592820/writing-backwards-compatible-android-code

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I can't apply this logic to the constructor. I think I need a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Check if we're running on GingerBread or above
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
    // do somthing 

// if not
} else {
    // do somthing
}
```