# Can I create app run with Jellybean API on android studio that have only Marshmallow 6.0 API

Tags: android-studio

In my android studio there is only the Marshmallow 6.0 API. Can i create the app also run on jellybean API without downloading the API of Jellybean? Thank you

Comment: beacuase you have not downloaded jelly bean 4.0 api. Open SDK manager and download.

Comment: Thank you. Can I do that without downloading jelly bean API?

Comment: Yes you can. But if you want to run your application in Emulator which is running with Jelly Bean you should download the Jelly Bean API.

Comment: thank you for spending your valuable time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can develop an app that runs also on an older version of Android. You should define "Min SDK version" for the module appropriately. If your code uses APIs that are not available on JellyBean, it's your responsibility to see that these APIs are not called. You can check [`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) at runtime. It is nice to use [**TargetAPI** annotations](http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck) to avoid warnings about such code.

See also *[Writing backwards compatible Android code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592820/writing-backwards-compatible-android-code)*